# Multi Crypto Algo Batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to find out what command(s) I can put in the Cryptonight area that will move batch to next command, myriad-groestl, upon being disconnected from cryptonight server. xmrig-nvidia utilizes a config fie in same Dir. I have --retry set to 0. Once disconnected it does not move onto next command....

```
:start  
@echo off    
REM GROESTL

C:\pathtominer/ccminer-x64 -r 0 -a Groestl -o server:port -u  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -p x -i 19

REM CRYPTONIGHT

C:\pathtominer\xmrig-nvidia

REM MYRIAD-GROESTL

C:\pathtominer/ccminer-x64 -r 0 -a myr-gr -o server:port -u xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -p x

timeout 1

goto start
```

This will move to next line in batch file but not close miner window for xmrig-nvidia. it leaves it open. These windows stack and when the algo xmrig-nvidia is set to (cryptonight) activates, most profitable to mine, drivers crash.

```
REM CRYPTONIGHT
set current_dir=%~dp0  

start C:\pathtominer\xmrig-nvidia
```

I have been looking at exit, call, taskill, verify and goto

Comment: Have you tried `start "" ` before each command?

Comment: yes start is in batch file. I took out 3 algos there are 8 in total.

Comment: please see new addition to question. I can get the batch to carry on now I just need cmd to kill the miner window that is now left open